# try catch not working in Node socket.io listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, websocket

I am working on an app that involves the use of WebSockets. I have the following code as a part of the application:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {

   let PLAYER = {};

   // Listener for event 1
   // Listener for event 2
   // ...

   socket.on('setName', ({name, role, room}) => {

        PLAYER.name = name;
        PLAYER.role = role;
        PLAYER.room = room;

        try{
            joinRoom(PLAYER);  // This function can throw an error
            socket.emit('roomJoin');
        }catch(e){
            socket.emit('error', e.message);
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Now, when the `joinRoom` function does throw an error, Node just crashes with the following exception:

```
events.js:306
    throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ('error message')
```

The `error` event is never emitted. What has made the try catch block fail?

Note: I am using TypeScript, but have removed type declarations in the above snippet as they shouldn't have anything to do with the problem.

Edit 1:

I have recreated the issue with simpler code as follows:

```
import express from 'express';
import socketio from 'socket.io';
import http from 'http';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

const checkLength = (bar) => {
    if(bar.length > 14){
        throw Error('word is too long!');
    }
    // ...
}

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('new socket connection');

    socket.on('foo', ({bar}) => {
        try{
            checkLength(bar);
        }catch(e){
            socket.emit('error', e.message);
            return;
        }
        console.log('app did not crash!');
    });
}
```

When the length of `bar` is greater than 14, the app crashes with the same error mentioned above.

Comment: Are you potentially missing catch statements on the .on events? I.e. io.on('connection', socket => {}).catch((err) => {}) ?. Which websocket library are you using?

Comment: @Phobos I'm using socket.io. I don't have a catch statement for the io.on('connection') event, but try-catch blocks in other events I'm listening works - just not this one, which is strange.

Comment: @Phobos The `on` method doesnt have error handling on its own. What could be an issue is if  `joinRoom` is calling an `async` function that's not being `await`-ed. If the `Promise` or `async` function, errors, it cannot be caught with a recular `try-catch` block, unless an `await` is done.

Comment: I agree with @Mike, ```joinRoom``` is likely an async function so you need to catch the error using ```joinRoom().catchError(error => /* handle error here */)```.

Comment: @Mike ```joinRoom``` is not ```async``` though - I'm not storing any persistent data so I'm only using an in-line array of ```ROOMS``` to store data. I also tried inserting ```throw Error('foo')``` into the first line of the above try-catch block, and the same error occured - that is surely not asynchronous.

Comment: Interesting! Do you think you can write up a similarly coded try catch issue? Maybe include some logic from your `joinRoom` so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Bro try instantiating your ```PLAYER``` variable like ```PLAYER = {}```

Comment: Right, or the issue could be coming from outside the trycatch.

Comment: @Mike I have edited my post to include a recreation of the problem. And I just accidentally removed the initialization for ```PLAYER``` while getting rid of type declarations, so it is correctly initialized in my code.

Comment: Much much appreciated. Although, the issue was staring at us in plain sight all along. I've added my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After replicating the server on my local machine, I realized you were calling `emit` on a reserved keyword for `socket.io`. When you call `socket.emit('error', e.message)`, there is an expected listener to exist. One like this:

```js
socket.on('error', err => {
  // An error occurred. 
})
```

You should use a different phrase for your `emit`. I personally use `oops` on my socket servers. `socket.emit('oops', {error})`. You can read more about error handling on their [page](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Event-%E2%80%98error%E2%80%99).

To add, `socket.emit('error')` does not pass the error or any data down to the client and instead is handled by the server, which is why you need to use a different phrase.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the promisses, and than you can profite from the then() method which also returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

So your code should be something like this:

```
import express from 'express';
import socketio from 'socket.io';
import http from 'http';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

const checkLength = (bar) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    if(bar.length > 14){
      // throw Error('word is too long!');
      reject('word is too long!')
    } else {
      resolve('app did not crash!')
    }
  });  
}

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('new socket connection');
  socket.on('foo', ({bar}) => {
    checkLength(bar).then((result) => {
        console.log('app did not crash!');
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("app did crash with this error:", err);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you hadn't initialized your `PLAYER` variable.

```
let PLAYER = {};
```

#EDIT 1:

try also adding an error handler for your socket server and log it to get an idea of what is causing the error.

```
socket.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I did it in my code and accidentally got rid of the initialization while removing type declarations for ```PLAYER```. Fixed it in my post just now - my bad!